# Making use of a Sharepoint Webpart within a non Sharepoint CMS?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, content-management-system

I am creating a new CMS for a customer using ASP.NET 3.5, SQL2008 and Windows Server 2008. The customer has some webparts that he uses in his current Sharepoint implementation and would like to have their functionality in the new CMS. I can install Windows Sharepoint Services on the Windows 2008 server. Is there a way I can display and use the Sharepoint Webparts (WSS not MOSS) within my ASP.Net pages so that we can use their functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASP.NET Web Parts in both the ASP.NET and WSS 3.0 environments, but not the other way around. The conversion should be pretty straight-forward, just a different namespace :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I guessed as much but thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So it is, the Sharepoint context is not optional.
Perhaps an IFRAME pointing to a Sharepoint URL....

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation - much appreciated